# Empty response from Twitter API v2 using Tweepy with organic_metrics

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to download tweets by a specific user from Twitter API v2 using `Tweepy`. For some reason, when I add `organic_metrics` to `tweet_fields` I get an empty response. If I remove `organic_metrics` I receive tweets as a response as expected.

Here is an MWE.

```py
import configparser
from pprint import PrettyPrinter
import tweepy
import logging
    
# Read Twitter authentication information from settings.ini
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read("settings.ini")
   
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    
pp = PrettyPrinter()
      
# Setup access to API
def connect_to_twitter_OAuth():
    client = tweepy.Client(
        consumer_key=config["AUTHENTICATION"]["CONSUMER_KEY"],
        consumer_secret=config["AUTHENTICATION"]["CONSUMER_SECRET"],
        access_token=config["AUTHENTICATION"]["ACCESS_TOKEN"],
        access_token_secret=config["AUTHENTICATION"]["ACCESS_SECRET"],
        wait_on_rate_limit=True,
    )
    _logger.debug("Authenticated with Twitter with user context.")
    
    return client
    
    
# Create API object
api = connect_to_twitter_OAuth()
    
tweet_fields = [
    "id",
    "text",
    "conversation_id",
    "created_at",
    "in_reply_to_user_id",
    "organic_metrics",
]
    
paginator = tweepy.Paginator(
    api.get_users_tweets,
    user_id,
    max_results=5,
    tweet_fields=tweet_fields,
    user_auth=True,
)
    
_logger.debug("Retrieving tweets from user.")
for tweet in paginator.flatten(limit=250):
    pp.pprint(tweet)
    _logger.debug("Tweet retrieved.")
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Documentation for `organic_metrics` says, _"Requires user context authentication."_ - which I am guessing is not actually what you have here ...?

Comment: I do. The `user_auth` parameter in `Paginator` enables user context authentication and the appropriate credentials are provided in the `Client` constructor. More info [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/authentication.html#id3).

Comment: I guess nobody knows why this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Non-public, organic, and promoted metrics are only available for Tweets that have been created within the last 30 days."

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/metrics

This is why you cannot paginate through responses. Hope this answers some of your confusion!